# jQuery - doesn't react to hasClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The jQuery hasClass() isn't working as it should. When I click on text it should give it a class (and it does), but it doesn't check if it has that class?

There is my code!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    
    $('#example').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass("redText");
    });
    
    if ( $('#example').hasClass("redText") ) {
        $('#example').addClass("bigText");
    }
    
    
});
```

```css
.redText{
  color: red;
}
.bigText{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">Hey</div>
```

Comment: Because the `if` executes once, when it's encountered in the script before the element has been clicked and before the class is added. If you want it to be executed after the class is added, then include it in the anonymous function that adds the class.

Comment: Providing a proper explanation of expected behavior would be helpful. Broken code often isn't a good substitute for explaining what you expect that code to do. See [ask]

Answer (score 2):

You're only adding the `redText` class when you click the div. When the `if` runs that class has not yet been added.

You need to either move the `if` into your click function, or remove the click function entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to do this, but I'm not completely sure;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').on('click', function() {
    if ( $('#example').hasClass("redText") ) {
      $('#example').addClass("bigText");
    }
    else{
      $(this).addClass("redText");
    }
});
```

This is a total guess, can you please try to explain what it is that you are trying to achieve in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your doing your `if` test only once when the page loads. You'd want to do that test when the element gets clicked and to show that, I've changed `addClass` to `toggleClass` so you can keep clicking.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("redText");
   
   if ( $('#example').hasClass("redText") ) {
     $('#example').addClass("bigText");
   }
  });
});
```

```css
.redText{
  color: red;
}
.bigText{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">Hey</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved in a single statement like below:

```
  $('#example').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass("redText bigText");
  });
```

The reason why your code is not working is because: Upon document load, first click listener gets registered. After which `if()` statement executes which does a lookup on all the `redText` class elements and finds none, and thus no `bigText` class gets added. Its not a LIVE listener that you are trying to achieve.